# Should I look further than the edit pushing it into the queue when deciding whether to re-open?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I recently voted to leave closed on an [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/8950659) in the reopen queue, for which the other option was correct.  I don't dispute value of the question, it should certainly be open.  What I'm wondering is if my process in reviewing these audits is inadequate.

When the reopen queue presents me a review triggered by an edit, my first question is usually "Is it remotely possible this edit fixed the problems the question was closed for?"

[In this case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31483539/revisions), three instances of "forget" were changed to "Forgot".  Trivial.  Certainly not substantive enough to have fixed a close-worthy problem.  My thinking has been, not much reason to look further.

Is my thinking on this incorrect?  Should I be reviewing the full content of the post, regardless of whether it was placed on the reopen queue as a result of an edit (even a trivial one), or being nominated for reopening by a community member?

Comment: You should review based on whether the question should be open or closed. Just because it was closed does not mean that it should be closed.

Comment: By that thinking *all* closures should go through the reopen queue, shouldn't they?

Comment: No, but if the OP thinks it was closed incorrectly. Their vote to reopen will put it in the reopen queue.

Comment: @TinyGiant is right here... before or after the edit - the question needn't be closed (and never was)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are reviewing in the CV-queue, there is just one thing to decide:

Should this question be closed, and if so, for what reason?

Similarly, in the re-open queue, the decision is:

**Should this question be open?**

Though in the latter case, you *might* also want to re-open in order to close with a (different) duplicate in some circumstances. Try to get help in a chatroom for that though, like the [SO Close Vote Reviewers Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), or it will probably go wrong.

In neither case does it matter whether someone edited, only what the state is *now*.
Though looking at the change *might* give you a hint, that can easily lead you astray.

Comment: Yeah; also, there are plenty of cases where questions enter the reopen queue due to an edit that's quickly followed by *another* edit, in which case you certainly don't want to base your decision on the changes made in just one of them.